# Data binding to an object containing a parameter in its constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm still getting my feet wet with WPF and programming in general, so please be gentle...

I'm creating a tool for moving data from one source to another. This involves mapping a bunch of different tables; rather than create a separate View and ViewModel for each, I'm trying to keep my ViewModel objects pretty generic and setup a DataTemplate for them in App.xaml. To accomplish this, the ViewModel object takes a parameter so that it knows what table to use, and I figured I could provide that parameter in the code-behind wherever the DataTemplate is used. (I know that's not pure MVVM, but it seemed reasonable for this project.)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get the databinding for my XAML DataTemplate to work, and I haven't been able to figure out where the breakdown is. Code is provided below; thanks in advance for any guidance!

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="BulkDataImportTool.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BulkDataImportTool.ViewModels"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:BulkDataImportTool.Models"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MappingViewModel}" x:Key="MappingDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label>Import File: </Label>
                    <Button>Select File</Button>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=ImportSourceFileName}" Width="200"></TextBox>
                </WrapPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Name="Mappings" Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Name="Padding" Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Name="UnmappedImportSourceColumns" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=TableMapping.Mappings}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Database Column" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ColumnMapping.DatabaseColumn.Name}">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Path=ColumnMapping.DatabaseColumn.Name}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Required?" Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Path=ColumnMapping.DatabaseColumn.IsRequired}" IsEnabled="False"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Import File Column" Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UnmappedImportSourceColumns}">
                                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=ImportSourceColumnName}"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Unmapped Columns from CSV"/>
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UnmappedImportSourceColumns}"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MappingViewModel:

```
using BulkDataImportTool.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BulkDataImportTool.ViewModels
{

    public class MappingViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {

        public ITableMapping TableMapping { get; private set; }
        //ITableMapping is a List<T> of ColumnMapping objects, which are composed a of a Column object and a string property. The Column object should stay static but the string property does not, so the latter implements IPropertyNotifyChanged. I'm not including the code for my models for the sake of brevity, but would be happy to add it if that would be helpful.    
        private string importSourceFileName;
        public string ImportSourceFileName
        {
            get { return this.importSourceFileName; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this.importSourceFileName, value, () => this.ImportSourceFileName); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> UnmappedImportSourceColumns;

        public MappingViewModel (ITableMapping tableMapping)
        {
            this.TableMapping = tableMapping;
        }
    }
}
```

Test View consuming the DataTemplate (ScratchXAML.xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="BulkDataImportTool.Views.ScratchXAML"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BulkDataImportTool.ViewModels"
        Title="ScratchXAML" Height="600" Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Name="testMappingDataTemplate" Content="{Binding Source=MappingViewModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MappingDataTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind for that view:

```
using System.Windows;
using BulkDataImportTool.ViewModels;
using BulkDataImportTool.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BulkDataImportTool.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ScratchXAML.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ScratchXAML : Window
    {
        public ScratchXAML()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var mappingVM = new MappingViewModel(new CertificatesTableMapping());

            //This stuff would be done elsewhere but is temporarily in the code-behind for quick testing.
            mappingVM.ImportSourceFileName = "Test File Name";

            const string unmappedColumn1 = "Unmapped Column 1";
            const string unmappedColumn2 = "Unmapped Column 2";
            var unmappedColumns = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            unmappedColumns.Add(unmappedColumn1);
            unmappedColumns.Add(unmappedColumn2);

            //Back to reality -- this would probably be done in the code-behind of my views, unless there's a better way.
            mappingVM.UnmappedImportSourceColumns = unmappedColumns;
            this.DataContext = mappingVM;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorter way to do it is move `InitializeComponent()` after the `DataLayer` is prepared :

```
public partial class ScratchXAML : Window
{
    public ScratchXAML()
    {

        var mappingVM = new MappingViewModel(new CertificatesTableMapping());

        //This stuff would be done elsewhere but is temporarily in the code-behind for quick testing.
        mappingVM.ImportSourceFileName = "Test File Name";

        const string unmappedColumn1 = "Unmapped Column 1";
        const string unmappedColumn2 = "Unmapped Column 2";
        var unmappedColumns = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        unmappedColumns.Add(unmappedColumn1);
        unmappedColumns.Add(unmappedColumn2);

        //Back to reality -- this would probably be done in the code-behind of my views, unless there's a better way.
        mappingVM.UnmappedImportSourceColumns = unmappedColumns;
        this.DataContext = mappingVM;

      //move this line after the Data has been prepared
      InitializeComponent();



    }
}
```

> ***Or the ideal way to do this is raise property change in the `setter` of all properties of `MappingViewModel`. And that is the recommended way of design also to support two way binding properly.***

**Update:**

Change your `Content` `Binding` as following:

```
<ContentControl Name="testMappingDataTemplate" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MappingDataTemplate}"/>
```

As `MappingViewModel` is already `DataContext` of parent element so that should directly get passed to `ContentControl`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Kylo! However, moving InitializeComponent() doesn't appear to have an effect, nor did raising PropertyChange in the setter of the other properties of the ViewModel. The properties that weren't raising PropertyChange were either OneTime bindings, or ObservableCollection<T> -- so I didn't think raising PropertyChanged would be needed for those.

Comment: @user2405502 Yes you were using ObservableCollection<T> but it will only raise change if Item is added or removed from collection. mappingVM.UnmappedImportSourceColumns = unmappedColumns this line will raise no change by default.

Comment: @user2405502 also see my update in answer if that helps. If update binding will work then you'll see my other points working.